# timing response speed of serial device

Tags: java

I comunicate with a serial device via bluetooth.
i send it pid and it responds to me with a data response.
i comunicate with him  with serial comunicatione one request-response. i want to measure how many response i receive in one second. i think that i have to know the moment when i do the request and the moment whene i receive the response and do the difference. The result(called delta) is the time-to response of device. in the end i have to do 1000ms/delta.

how can calculate it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the before/after time in ms using `System.currentTimeMillis()` or in nanoseconds using `System.nanoTime()`.

Note:

> This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily
>   nanosecond accuracy

(from [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29))

Answer (score 0):

Long st = System.currentTimeMillis();

// send/receive

Long et = System.currentTimeMillis();

Long t = et - st; // consumed time of send/receive